# Problem with permalink routing?

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have a post (to keep it simple, "dogs" with content on dogs).  The permalink lists my site url and then /dogs.  When I edit the post, it is all about dogs.  But when I click on the link as if someone visiting the site, it takes me to "cats" (/cats).  I've torn both the /dogs and /cats posts apart and recreated them from scratch but the problem persists.  I don't want to change my global permalink settings because I have three dozen posts.  What can the problem be and how can I fix it?

Comment: hm! is it just these two posts? no other posts are doing this?